# Weka - limit classification errors of a certain type

Tags: weka

I am trying to use weka's logistic regression. Is there any way to tell weka to try an minimize errors of a certain type? I don't mind getting more errors of a classified as b, but I want to minimize the number of b classified as a.

This is my output:

```
Logistic Regression with ridge parameter of 1.0E-8
Coefficients...
                                    Class
Variable                              yes
=========================================
cmapArithAvg                      28.9022
cnllArithAvg                       1.8342
cmapGeoAvg                       -92.0111
cnllGeoAvg                        -0.6321
avgCatchAllScorer                       0
cmapMin                       -15333.0622
cmapMinInternal                15210.7515
cnllMin                            0.0267
cmapStdev                         -0.9583
cnllStdev                         -2.0748
numphones                          0.3234
Intercept                         12.3432


Odds Ratios...
                                    Class
Variable                              yes
=========================================
cmapArithAvg         3.564876537642066E12
cnllArithAvg                       6.2601
cmapGeoAvg                              0
cnllGeoAvg                         0.5315
avgCatchAllScorer                       1
cmapMin                                 0
cmapMinInternal                  Infinity
cnllMin                            1.0271
cmapStdev                          0.3835
cnllStdev                          0.1256
numphones                          1.3818


Time taken to build model: 0.67 seconds
Time taken to test model on training data: 0.28 seconds

=== Error on training data ===

Correctly Classified Instances       11383               95.2791 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       564                4.7209 %
Kappa statistic                          0.7434
Mean absolute error                      0.0723
Root mean squared error                  0.1883
Relative absolute error                 36.4503 %
Root relative squared error             59.8021 %
Total Number of Instances            11947     


=== Confusion Matrix ===

     a     b   <-- classified as
 10442   171 |     a = yes
   393   941 |     b = no



=== Stratified cross-validation ===

Correctly Classified Instances       11376               95.2206 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       571                4.7794 %
Kappa statistic                          0.7401
Mean absolute error                      0.0726
Root mean squared error                  0.189 
Relative absolute error                 36.5861 %
Root relative squared error             60.0198 %
Total Number of Instances            11947     


=== Confusion Matrix ===

     a     b   <-- classified as
 10439   174 |     a = yes
   397   937 |     b = no
```

Comment: AFAIK there's no direct way to do this. Most classifiers don't have a concept of this. What you could try is duplicating the instances of the class that you want to put more emphasis on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Cost Sensitive classification. You can define a cost matrix that assigns much bigger cost to those errors you want to minimize, and as most classifiers try to minimize average error, they will try to avoid those errors.

You can do this in WEKA by using the meta-classifier `CostSensitiveClassifier`. An example in the weka Explorer is shown in [this blog post](http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.com.es/2008/03/class-imbalanced-distribution-and-weka.html).